# Having a separate project for satellite assembly for globalization for a solution with a Silverlight and ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, localization, globalization, satellite-assembly

I'm trying to figure out a way to have a separate project for my two applications that are in the same solution. Can this be done? I can't find any examples and even tutorials for globalization with satellite assemblies are pretty bad. I want both applications to share a common base of resources. Does anyone know how I would go about this? Silverlight can't reference non silverlight projects so that is a hurdle already.

Comment: Are you talking about 2 Siverlight projects? Or one Silverlight and one "something else" project?

Comment: One silverlight project and one asp.net project. The asp.net project has its own pages and it integrates a silverlight control as well. Also I have class libraries that need to use the resources as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add separate project as Silverlight class library project and reference it from both Silverlight and ASP.NET project.
Visual Studio may throw warnings in this case, but this works fine.

Comment: Well some of the class libraries are shared with other project. SO I can't depend on people having silverlight installed.